# Access Component Properties From Extending Component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have a component with a public variable declared

```
[Bindable]
public var mnuSource:String;
```

When I extend this component, I can reference mnuSource (it compiles) but Runtime complains about the property not being accessible (error 1056).

How do you modify / declare component properties so they are actually available to other components?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some more code of original and extended component? You can skip unrelated details in that code.

Comment: You've done it correctly; but show the full error and the line that throws it form you subcomponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as The_asMan but in MXML

Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:local="*" 
               >
    <local:SomeExtendedComponent />
</s:Application>
```

Some Base Component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var mnuSource:String;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Group>
```

Extended Component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:SomeBaseComponent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:local="*"
                         creationComplete="cc(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function cc(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                mnuSource = "Hi there!";
                Alert.show(mnuSource);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Label text="{mnuSource}" />
</local:SomeBaseComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code but should work and give you a good idea how to extend a class.

```
MyBaseClass.as
package{
  public class MyBaseClass{
    public var someVar:String;
    public function MyBaseClass( )::void{
      this.someVar = 'set from MyBaseClass';
    }
  }
}


MyBaseclassExtended.as
package{
  public class MyBaseclassExtended extends MyBaseClass{
    public MyBaseclassExtended( ){
      this.someVar = 'Set from MyBaseclassExtended';
    }
  }
}


call it like so
var asdf:MyBaseclassExtended = new MyBaseclassExtended();
trace( asdf.someVar ) // Set from MyBaseclassExtended
```